# Can you highlight where I've gone wrong

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax, javascript-objects, curly-braces

I've been working on this for over 12 hours.

I really enjoy coding but I'm very bad at it.

Could you please highlight in red where I've gone wrong in this code?

```js
(function (window) {
var names = {"Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"};
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
if (firstLetter === 'j')  || 'J'{
    byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
  } else {
    helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
  } 
}

})(window);

(function (window) {

var speakWord = "Hello";

var helloSpeaker = speakWord;

helloSpeaker.speak(name) = fuction () 
    
(speakWord + " " + name);

window.helloSpeaker = helloSpeaker;
console.log(window);})

(function (window) {

var speakWord = "Good Bye";

var byeSpeaker = speakWord;

byeSpeaker.speak(name) = function () {
    
(speakWord + " " + name);}

window.byeSpeaker = byeSpeaker;

console.log(window);})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Module 4 Solution Starter</title>
  <script src="SpeakHello.js"></script>
  <script src="SpeakGoodBye.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Module 4 Solution Starter</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to loop for hello name but goodbye for names beginning with J.

If you can provide more feedback I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Natasha

Comment: The browser console is showing you where the error is.  You're trying to use `{}` to define an array instead of `[]`.

Comment: Array should be declared with `[]` as @David mentioned, not with `{}`. Your if statement is wrong as @DerEchteKroate mentioned below. Your firstLetter variable is not declared anywhere. Other than these your function declarations below are also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement is bad. It should be like this:

```js
if (firstLetter === 'j' || firstLetter === 'J') {
```